# Add condition to cookie check function without causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that checks for a cookie on page load and if the cookie does not exist the user is redirected to a certain log in page based on conditions. I am trying to add another condition to the cookie check but it is creating an infinite loop. Is there a way to allow another condition?

```
function checkCookie() {
    var current_url = window.location.pathname;
    var logInCookie = _siteNS.Utils.readCookie('x-access');

    if (!logInCookie) {
      if (
        window.location.toString().includes('-fr') &&
        current_url != '/landing-fr.html'
      ) {
        window.location.replace('/landing-fr.html');
      } else if (
        window.location.href.indexOf('-fr') === -1 &&
        current_url != '/landing.html'
      ) {
        window.location.replace('/landing.html');
      } else if (
        window.location.href.indexOf('-fr') === -1 &&  *=== This is creating infinite loop===*
        current_url === '/Important_Safety_Information.html'
      ) {
        window.location.replace('/Important_Safety_Information.html');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: In what way is this an "infinite loop"?  What specifically is happening?  What is that condition even attempting to do?  It looks like you're trying to re-load the current page, which if you do that on page load would of course... keep reloading the current page.

Comment: As of now if the user tries to go to a page without logging in it redirects them to a certain log in page. works perfectly.

What I want to do is if the user goes to '/Important_Safety_Information.html' stay there and do not redirect to the log in page

Comment: But that's not what your new condition is doing.  It's redirecting the user to the page they are *already on*.  So when your page loads, the first thing you do is reload the page.  Why?

Comment: Not really sure how to go about this. hence why I am asking the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're redirecting the user back to the page they are already on.  When the user loads that same page, it's going to invoke that same logic again and redirect the user again... to the same page.

From a comment on the question above:

> What I want to do is if the user goes to '/Important_Safety_Information.html' stay there and do not redirect

If you don't want to redirect the user then... don't redirect the user.  Just remove that last `else if` block entirely since you don't want to perform that operation.  Or, at worst, if you need to include this condition in an ongoing list of conditions then simply keep the block empty:

```
else if (
  window.location.href.indexOf('-fr') === -1 &&
  current_url === '/Important_Safety_Information.html'
) { /* do nothing */ }
```

Comment: Ok I understand the logic now but this still redirects the user to the login page, I must be going wrong elsewhere. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out. I just added a url check of the page I want to stay on before I do the checkCookie because I realized the cookie has nothing to do with the user being able to access the page I want. Thanks again @David!